# Secure IBM HTTP Server

Tags: apache, security, websphere

I am tasked with securing IHS. I know that IHS is derivative of Apache. My question is does anyone know if there is a white paper or web site that outlines how to secure IHS? Or should I be falling back on the Apache security configuration document.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by saying securing the IHS?

Comment: I am looking for hardening procedure that is different from Apache's

Answer (score 1):

In general IHS is based on Apache, so you can follow any security documents related to Apache in most cases. You should install latest fix pack for your IHS version as it may update underlying Apache also.

To check Apache version being used you can issue the following command:

```
// on windows
C:\ibm\HTTPServer\bin>apache -V
 // on linux
#./apachectl -V

Server version: IBM_HTTP_Server/8.5.5.0 (Unix)
Apache version: 2.2.8 (with additional fixes)
```

Comment: What I am looking for is any part of IHS that needs to be hardened differently from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Http Server does not support specific modules that relate to security.

For example instead of **mod_ssl** there is **mod_ibm_ssl**.

A very useful FAQ page on almost every aspect IBM Http Server is the [following](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/questions.html).